# Which Laravel 8 CMS to learn as Beginner?

Tags: web-hosting, php, web-development, cms, laravel

I'm learning `web development` and need to provide a `simple CMS` for a customer, with which he can manage his website. For now `creating posts` on his website is all he needs.

There seem to be a ton of CMS packages for Laravel. Which one would you recommend for me to learn?

Also: Some packages seem to require an initial setup and can't be integrated in existing projects. For flexibility's sake I'd prefer if a package can be integrated in an existing project, should the need arise.

Comment: Use Wordpress for the *off-topic* CMS. For your learning Statamic looks really sick - https://statamic.com/